# Where to put generated certicate for user

Tags: centos, authentication, certificates

I was following this [tutorial](http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/) and I want to implement mutual authentication between server and client, where server and CA (certificate authority) is the same thing.

I reached the last step and I don't know where to put the device certificate.

> The process for creating your own certificate authority is pretty
> straight forward
>
> 1. Create a private key
> 2. Self-sign
> 3. Install root CA on your various workstations
>
> Once you do that, every device that you manage via HTTPS just needs to
> have its own certificate created with the following steps:
>
> 1. Create CSR for device
> 2. Sign CSR with root CA key

I can't access server now with https, I have to do something that is not written in the article.
Please help.

Comment: What web server software are you using, apache?

Comment: yes , apache web server , I've added an exception and now it's logged to the page with https but seems there's work to do with certificates and apache httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that I have to generate three certificates :

1. one as CA (self-signed)
2. second for web server signed by CA ,put as Apache certificate in SSL configuration , would be added in Authority tab in user browser
3. third for user signed by CA ,  would added in your certificates in user browser

Thanks for help .